# How to check out submodules on azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I've read this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops but as an Azure beginner it's not very helpful.

I've got two repos in GitHub, one references the other via submodules. I've granted Azure Pipelines access to both repos in GitHub.

I've followed the [Getting Started Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=azdevops&tabs=net%2Cyaml%2Cbrowser%2Ctfs-2018-2) to making a new pipeline, and it's added an `azure-pipelines.yml` to my repos. It looks like this:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

my `.gitmodules` did look like this:

```
[submodule "src/MySubmodulePath"]
    path = src/MySubmodulePath
    url = git@github.com:trullock/MySubmoduleProject.git
```

but I've changed it to use HTTPS as alluded to:

```
[submodule "src/MySubmodulePath"]
    path = src/MySubmodulePath
    url = https://github.com/trullock/MySubmoduleProject.git
```

I can still see in the Checkout step for the Job in Pipelines, and it's not checking the submodules out because the build fails because they're missing:

`git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin`

I've read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout and can see it shows the `submodules: true|recursive` setting, but where do I put this?

Putting it under the `steps` key causes a syntax error on build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had a similar problem, but I needed to enable LFS, the configuration should work in the same way though.

In your case this would be:

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Imagine if the docs had examples!